# Quartz job not execute without Task.Delay

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz

This is my job:

```
public class MyJob: IJob
{
        public static bool run = true;

        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            logger.Info("Start MyJob");
        }
}
```

And here is my class Program:

```
 
        private static ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private static IJob MyJob;
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                logger.Info("Start");


                RunProgram().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                logger.Info("Completed");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"error");
            }
        }
```

```
        private static async Task RunProgram()
        {
            try
            {
                ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .Build();
                
                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

                await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);


                await scheduler.Start();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));


                await scheduler.Shutdown();
                
                
            }
            catch (SchedulerException se)
            {
                await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync(se.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The code above is working.

The trigger set MyJob run every 5 seconds. The Task.Delay() make the program terminate after 10 seconds.
So MyJob will be execute twice.

I want to wait until the job finish instead of setting timer, so I read the quartz tutorial and modify RunProgram() like this:

```
        private static async Task RunProgram()
        {
            try
            {
                ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
                await scheduler.Start();                                           //++

                IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .Build();

                ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .StartNow()
                    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                        .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                        .RepeatForever())
                    .Build();

                await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

                //--await scheduler.Start();
                //--await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
                //--await scheduler.Shutdown();

            }
            catch (SchedulerException se)
            {
                await Console.Error.WriteLineAsync(se.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Then MyJob never be executed.

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try removing StartNow(). from below code

```
       ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .Build();
```

Also, try using crone trigger as mentioned [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I try to remove StartNow() but nothing happen. And the CronTrigger not even work on my origin code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Console.ReadLine() in your Main method. This will prevent the termination of your application.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        logger.Info("Start");


        RunProgram().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
         logger.Info("Completed");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error($"error");
    }
}
```

A better solution can be found [here](https://www.olivercoding.com/2018-06-29-quartz/)

Comment: Thank you for your answering. This still can not prevent the job be terminated

Comment: With this solution and the second version of your RunProgram(), the job is executing every 5 seconds on my end. I believe you are asking something else. Maybe your job takes more than 5 sec? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, my job takes more than 5s. The problem is I can't even fire my job with second version of my RunProgram().